# Trying to access localhost from a Java restAdapter on Android

Tags: java, android, localhost

I'm making an android application wich uses a web service. To access to it, we use a restAdapter. This is the code:

```
private String URL_PLACE = "http://myaddresstomywebservice";

public RouteCLlegar(Context ctx) {
    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL_PLACE)
            .build();
    cLlegar = restAdapter.create(CLlegar.class);
}
```

When we access the web service hosted on the web, it works, but when we use localhost, it doesn't.

```
private String URL_PLACE = "http://localhost:53285";

public RouteCLlegar(Context ctx) {
    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(URL_PLACE)
            .build();
    cLlegar = restAdapter.create(CLlegar.class);
}
```

It gives this error:

24963-25327/ni.femer.busesmg.app I/ERROR﹕ el error java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 53285) after 15000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused

[image]

**How can i access localhost from my rest adapter?**

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect, localhost is your Android device. If you realy want to access something on localhost, you would have to deploy a http Server in your Android device.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can run your application on an Android emulator and use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost`.
2. You can use a local IP address of your PC (check it with `ipconfig`, should be something like `192.168.1.x`), if it's on the same wireless network with your Android device.

Don't forget to specify also a port number.